# Allow X nested tags only

Tags: php, nested

Let's say we have a tag called test, i.e. `[code]`.

What I'd like to do, is I'd like to only allow up to X other `[code]` tags inside of every main `[code]` tag in a string, which means the most inner ones would get removed.

So, for example, if X = 4, the following string:

```
[code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]e[code]f[code]g[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]
```

Would become:

```
[code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]e[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]
```

And the following string:

```
[code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]TEST[/code][code]e[code]f[code]g[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]
```

Would become:

```
[code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]TEST[/code][code]e[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]
```

The goal here is to not have more than a few nested [code] elements inside of a code element, so it doesn't get too messy.

I'm wondering how to implement this, just trying to think of an algorithm and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [joke] Use Regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/420001

*Edit*: In all seriousness, I think you need to describe the problem you're trying to solve here, not the solution you think will work. This feels very messy. What is your end goal?

Comment: how are you outputting the string?

Comment: I should have noted this is not HTML, but some kind of bbcode, so I need to solve this programmatically.

Comment: What are you trying to restrict the nesting of?

Comment: @Josh Yeah, I guess I should have actually described the situation, I'll edit it so it's more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gonna be quite a waste since it would be so easy to add multiple tag support and so on here.
You pretty much have to do fully blown out tree parsing either way.

Note that invalid input is not handled in any way, tags must be properly balanced

```
function get_node_contents( $node ) {
    $orig = $node;
    $ret = "[code]" . $node->content;

    if( @$node->children ) {
        foreach( $node->children as $node ) {
            $ret .= get_node_contents( $node );
        }
    }


    if( @$orig->endContent ) {
        $ret .= $orig->endContent;
    }
    return $ret."[/code]";

}

function reduce_depth( $str, $maxDepth = 4 ) {
    $index = 0;
    $len = strlen( $str );
    $reg = '/(\[code\]|\[\/code\])/';

    $root = new stdClass;
    $root->children = array();
    $depth = 0;
    $ret = "";

    $pos = strpos( $str, "[code]" );

    if( $pos ) {
        $ret .= substr( $str, 0, $pos - 0);
    }

    while( $index < $len  ) {

        if( !preg_match( $reg, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $index )) {
            break;
        }

        $index = ( $matches[1][1] + strlen( $matches[1][0] ) );
        $tag = $matches[1][0];

        $next = preg_match( $reg, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $index );
        $content = "";

        if( $next ) {
            $content = substr( $str, $index, $matches[1][1] - $index );
        }

        if( $tag === "[code]" ) {
            if( $depth === 0 ) {
                $parent = $root->children[] = new stdClass;
                $parent->content = $content;
                $depth++;
            }
            else if ( $depth++ > $maxDepth ) {

                continue;
            }
            else {
                if( !@$parent->children ) {
                    $parent->children = array();
                }
                $child = $parent->children[] = new stdClass;
                $child->content = $content;
                $child->parent = $parent;
                $parent = $child;
            }        
        }
        else {                
            $depth--;

            if( @$parent->parent ) {
                $parent = $parent->parent;
            }

            if( @$content ) {
                $parent->endContent = $content;
            }                

        }

    }


    foreach( $root->children as $node ) {
        $ret .= get_node_contents( $node );
    }

    $ret .= substr( $str, $index, $len - $index );


    return $ret;

}

echo reduce_depth( "asdasdas[code]l[/code][code]a[code]lol[/code][code]b[code]c[code]d[code]e[code]f[code]g[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]aasdasdsasd", 4 ). "\n";
echo reduce_depth( "[code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]e[code]f[code]g[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]", 4 ) . "\n";
echo reduce_depth( "[code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]TEST[/code][code]e[code]f[code]g[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]", 4 ) . "\n";
echo reduce_depth("[code][code]bugi[/code]bugi2[/code]", 1) . "\n"; 
echo reduce_depth("[code][code]bugi[/code]bugi2[code]bugi3[/code]bugi4[code]bugi5[/code]bugi6[/code]", 3) . "\n"; 


/*
    asdasdas[code]l[/code][code]a[code]lol[/code][code]b[code]c[code]d[code]e[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]aasdasdsasd
    [code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]e[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]
    [code]a[code]b[code]c[code]d[code]TEST[/code][code]e[/code][/code][/code][/code][/code]
    [code][code]bugi[/code]bugi2[/code]
    [code][code]bugi[/code][code]bugi3[/code][code]bugi5[/code]bugi6[/code]

*/
```

Comment: Amazing, you shouldn't have bothered, really, I was only trying to figure out how to it by myself. Thanks!

Comment: @Lior no problem, I'll probably have use for similar code in the future anyway.... probably

Comment: Well, tried figure it out on my own, but I'm unable to. Please try running the following: reduce_depth("[code][code]1[/code]2[/code]", 1); The string is supposed to stay the same, but it doesn't. The code always ignores the text between [/code] tags.

Comment: @Lior I have found the bug, it's because I ignored that a particular [code] might have content AFTER it's children as well. I'll edit in the fix, just testing a bit more.

Comment: @Lior nvm it still bugs out if there is multiple points where a single [code] might have content. I suggest you use JBBCode :p, this realization would require some reworking of the overall algorithm which I don't have time for right now. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyways :) Will try working it out on my own, as JJBCode is an overkill for such a thing as nesting limitation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use JBBCode:

http://jbbcode.com/docs#definingNewCodes

```
addBBCode's fifth and last parameter is a nest limit. By default 
the nest limit is -1, meaning no limit. Nest limits allow you to 
define a bbcode such that if the bbcode is embedded multiple times, 
elements nested beyond the nest limit will be omitted from the output.
```

Comment: Using their solution (not the whole parser of course, just the way they limit nesting) is quite an overkill, but thanks, I'll use it if I have no other choice.

Comment: @Lior Well, you can always just look at the source, and see how they implement the N-limiting: https://github.com/jacksono/jBBCode

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, I looked at the source and their solution basically requires using the whole thing, since it requires the TokenManager, the Node, the TextNode, the ElementNode and the DocumentElement classes (at the very least), and I thought I'd better first try to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're going for here, but if you're outputting this as HTML, you can just add this rule to your stylesheet:

```
test test test test test { display: none; }
```

Obviously, it'll have to be a real element, since `<test>` isn't part of html.

Comment: @Josh: Not in IE. It'll only work in IE if you run `document.createElement('test')` first.

Comment: Gotcha. Although OP just said it was BBCode, not HTML, so CSS probably won't work in this case anyway.